# Firebase database 6.16.0 is not working in unity 2020 but works in mobile build

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

I recently upgraded to Firebase 6.16 sdk because of an error in which unity 2020 was crashing after pressing play the second time. The ugrade fixed that error.

However, now my realtime database is not being accessed in the editor but it works fine in the mobile build.

The error that I get is that "The hostname of this url "https://any_url/2" is different from the database url "https://any_url/.
I am passing the database reference to get the values and this is working in the mobile build. In editor it seems to compare the database reference with the node tree parent reference. I do not understand why. This was working in unity 2020 before updating to the last firebase sdk.

I am accessing a node of the realtime database which I am passing as a database reference. I have initialised the default instance of firebase database with the main head of the tree.

I cannot find any results related to this particular error so I think this might be new as well.
This is the complete error that I am facing.

The hostname of this url (https://xyz.firebaseio.com/abc/2) is different from the database url (https://xyz.firebaseio.com/)
UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)

```
    private void Start()
    {
        FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance.SetEditorDatabaseUrl(firebaseDatabaseUrl);
    }

    public void SetDatabaseReference(string name)
    {
        _databaseReference = 
        FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.GetReferenceFromUrl(GetDatabaseURL(name));
    }

    public IEnumerator LoadParticularDatabase()
    {
        DataLoaded = false;
        
        _databaseReference.GetValueAsync().ContinueWith(task =>
        {
            GameData loadedData = new GameData();
            RoundData roundData = new RoundData();
            if (task.IsFaulted)
            {
                Debug.Log("Couldn't access");
                return;
            }
            else if (task.IsCompleted)
            {
                Debug.Log("Accessed");
                string dataText = task.Result.GetRawJsonValue();
               
                roundData = JsonUtility.FromJson<RoundData>(dataText);
                loadedData.allRoundData = roundData;
                allRoundData = loadedData.allRoundData;
            }
            DataLoaded = true;
        });
        
        yield return new WaitUntil(() => DataLoaded == true);
        
        yield return DataLoaded;
    }

    private IEnumerator WaitToLoadDB(string dbName)
    {
        DataController.instance.SetDatabaseReference(dbName);
        
        StartCoroutine(DataController.instance.LoadParticularDatabase());
        Debug.Log("Waiting for data to load...");
        yield return new WaitUntil(() => DataController.instance.DataLoaded == true);

        if (DataController.instance.DataLoaded == true)
        {
            dbLoadFinished = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does it work if you remove the `SetEditorDatabaseUrl`? (this call is no longer necessary)

Comment: Hello @PatrickMartin I was never able to get 6.16 working. Sadly for me, the error persisted.

I was not able to test it without this call "SetEditorDatabaseUrl" as I had already downgraded to 6.15.2 as suggested by you.
For now this is doing the task for me.

Thank you for helping out.

Comment: No worries, and the team is scrambling to get a good 6.16.1 patch going!